# null-conditional, null-coalescing, enumerable and params keyword

Tags: c#, ienumerable, null-coalescing-operator, null-conditional-operator, params-keyword

I didn't know what better title to chose for the question as I don't know what's the problem. Consider the following small C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    F1(null);
}
public static void F1(int[] values)
{
    F2(1, values?[0] as object ?? new object[0]);
    F2(2, values?.Select(v => (object)v) ?? new object[0]);
    F2(3, values?.Select(v => (object)v).ToArray() ?? new object[0]);
}
public static void F2(int idx, params object[] values)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"count {idx}: '{values?.Count()}'");
}
```

It outputs:

```
count 1: '1'
count 2: '1'
count 3: '0'
```

Why the first 2 are 1? If I use the Immediate Window in Visual Studio, all the following are null:

```
values?[0]
null
values?.Select(v => (object)v)
null
values?.Select(v => (object)v).ToArray()
null
```

Comment: Because you are passing a new object, not an array, which is automatically wrapped in an array due to the `params` keyword. See how the parameter gets converted to an array when the code is lowered if you paste it into https://sharplab.io/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you might know, for a `params` parameter of type `object[]`, you can either pass an expression of type `object` (which implicitly creates a `object[]` and the `object` you passed will be treated as an element of the array), or an expression of type `object[]` (which will be passed to the method "directly").

```
object[] x = new object[0];
object y = new object();
F2(1, x); // values?.Count() is 0
F2(2, y); // values?.Count() is 1
```

Notably, this depends on the compile-time type of the expression only (unless there is `dynamic` stuff going on). Therefore, an expression of type `object` will be wrapped in an array, even if the expression evaluates to an `object[]` object at runtime.

```
object z = new object[0];
F2(3, z); // values?.Count() is 1
```

With that in mind, it should be clear why your code behaves like that. Both of these expressions are of type `object`:

```
values?[0] as object ?? new object[0]
values?.Select(v => (object)v) ?? new object[0]
```

`values?[0] as object` is of type `object`, and `values?.Select(v => (object)v)` is of type `IEnumerable<object>`. But the right hand side of `??` is of type `object[]`. So the whole expression is of type `object` in both cases.

In the case of

```
values?.Select(v => (object)v).ToArray() ?? new object[0]
```

`values?.Select(v => (object)v).ToArray()` is of type `object[]`, the same type as `new object[0]`, so the whole expression is of type `object[]`.